# How to diagnose a faulty driveshaft?

Tags: honda, civic, drive-shaft

I've been getting a knocking noise from under near clutch, break area and to left of clutch I guess.

Mechanic told me there's nothing wrong with driveshaft.

Another mechanic told me he couldn't find the problem elsewhere, when vehicle is stationary on ramp and he's moving it there are no noises so it means it's the driveshaft.

Not sure what to believe but seems second mechanic did it by exclusion.

Is there a way to physically diagnose a faulty drive shaft?

Car is a Civic VTI EM1 99 or Civic SI as known in the States I believe.

Thanks

Comment: Its hard sometimes unless you remove the cv axle for examination. CV axle outer joints can make a loud popping noise when moving while turning hard, this is a sign of a cv shaft needing replaced. How many miles on the civic?

Comment: @Moab 160 though could be more as apparently these cars get clocked a lot.

Comment: I would have to hear the noise, cv joint poping is very distinct.